# Splash screen for product category doesn't show

Tags: 7

The version is Drupal 7. It is a B2B inquiry store and I just started at the company whom asked me to fix the splash screen function on their store.

The menu on the site looks like this:

```
-Main cat 1
   - sub cat 1
   - sub cat 2
   - sub cat 3
   - sub cat 4
-Main cat 2
   - sub cat 1
   - sub cat 2
   - sub cat 3
   - sub cat 4
```

and they would like to show some information and some picture when you click on the main category.

When I click on `Edit` for the `Main Cat` page, I can set some pictures and some text I would like to have displayed, but when I look at the page after I save, I still only get to see products.

This is how the settings look like:

[image: settings]

And this is the result:

[image]

My question would be if anybody has any idea of what may cause the problem? Maybe somewhere I am supposed to uncheck a box or something?

Comment: thank you @bsfoo116.. It was my plan to put the images inside the question, but because I only have 1 point in reputation it wouldn't let me, so I had to think different.